# Can't run my app with Genymotion

Tags: java, android, android-studio, genymotion

I have installed `Genymotion` in my `osx` (I am using `Android Studio`). The `Genymotion` icon appears in the `ide` toolbar but I can't run my app with this emulator, since it is not shown in my `AVD manager`. How can I make this work ?

Edit :@pyus13, I can't find any bottom tab button, here's a screen

[image]

Comment: Have you tried stopping and re-starting adb?

Comment: And Genymotion is running right?

Comment: @cbrulak yes genymotion is running right

Comment: @RocketSpock I have quit the ide and launch it again. Am supposed to anything else ?

Comment: @RocketSpock means adb. The Android Debug Bridge. what do you get when you run this command: "adb devices"

Comment: @cbrulak is correct.  If you open terminal and type `adb devices` it will show you the connected devices (virtual or real).  To stop adb type `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server` to restart it (alternatively you can just call `adb devices` after you kill it).

Comment: Try to Install the GenyMotion plugin again. I tried and everything works fine for me.

Comment: @RocketSpock adb devices outputs nothing but if I launch the `genymotion` device from the `ide``genimotion` icon, I get the expected `ip` when running `adb devices`. So what should I do  ?

Comment: @cbrulak see my answer to RocketSpock

Comment: If it is showing up when running `adb devices` now, you should be able to run from Android Studio and select the device.

Comment: @RocketSpock : here's what I did : I launched the genymotion device from the `ide` `genymotion` icon, when running `adb devices`, I get the `ip`. Then when running my app, I am not asked to choose the `emulator` and it keeps to automatically launch an older `emulator`. So I went to `edit configurations` of the `run` button and in the `emulator` select box, I didn't find any trace of the `genymotion` emulator. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: "since it is not shown in my AVD manager" , GenyMotion Emulator never be visible their. Check your Devices tab inside Android tab on bottom. Can you attach of you ide screenshot in the question with Devices Tab opened and genymotion running.

Comment: @pyus13 here's a screen for update, but I can't see any `Devices tab inside Android tab on bottom`

Comment: @RocketSpock is there a command line to launch the emulator as this `/home/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk/tools/emulator -avd $myEmulator -netspeed full -netdelay none` ?

Comment: I'm not sure if Genymotion allows you to use terminal to start an emulator, however you can use their "terminal" which I haven't used before.  When you modified the run configuration did you change the "Target Device" option to "Show chooser dialog"?

Comment: @RocketSpock interesting, you're right, I am now able to choose. But when I run with the genimotion device, I get this message `pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.newsfeeder
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]` btw, in the chooser dialog box, this device compatibility is set to `no`. Any idea ?

Comment: The device compatibility `no` can typically be ignored, since it just compares the built sdk version to the devices running version.  As far as the `[INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]` message goes, I believe that is in reference to your minSDK (in AndroidManifest.xml) being greater than that of the device. (or something similar to that)

Comment: @RocketSpock, indeed, I have this line in my log `Requires newer sdk version #14 (current version is #10)` What type of device should use because my min-target is `14` ?

Comment: Typically you will want to use a device for each API version between (including) your minSDK version and targetSDK.  Additionally, I usually test from minSDK to the current version.  For just day-to-day development testing though I usually use the most up to date version. (For Genymotion I think that is 4.2, though they may have updated since I last used them)

Comment: thank you so much. Could you post what you told as an answer so I can validate it for the community ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarize for others:

1. Start the genymotion emulator you want to install/run the application on
2. Open `terminal` and restart adb with the commands `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server`
3. In terminal type `adb devices` and make sure the emulator shows up
4. In Android Studio under the run configurations change "Target Device" to "Show chooser dialog"
5. Run the application as normal and, when prompted, select the genymotion emulator.

Comment: I did all of these steps , and doesn't help at all ... do you have other alternatives... thanks anyway